# IList<T> vs IEnumerable<T>. What is more efficient IList<T> or IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

What is more efficient way to make methods return `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

`IEnumerable<T>` it is immutable collection but `IList<T>` mutable and contain a lot of useful methods and properties.

To cast `IList<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` it is just reference copy:

```
IList<T> l = new List<T>();
IEnumerable<T> e = l;
```

To cast `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` we need to iterate each element or to call `ToList()` method:

```
IEnumerable<T>.ToList();
```

or may pass `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` constructor which doing the same iteration somewhere within its constructor.

```
List<T> l = new List<T>(e);
```

Which cases you think is more efficient? Which you prefer more in your practice?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as efficiency is concerned both are interfaces so the efficiency will depend on the actual concrete class you are returning. As a rule of thumb you should always return the type that's highest in the object hierarchy that works for the consumers of this method. In your case `IEnumerable<T>`. If the consumers of the class need to add elements, access elements by index, remove elements you are better off using an `IList<T>`.

So as always in programming: *it depends* :-)

Comment: For example if i implemented method which returns 'IEnumerable<T>' and then on another stage of development i may need to heave 'IList<T>' in that case i need to cast 'IEnumerable<T>' to 'IList<T>'. Also i may duplicate this method to create new one which returns 'IList<T>'. But i dont think that duplication is a good choice. But to cast from 'IEnumerable<T>' to 'IList<T>' it is only reference copy another way 'IList<T>' to 'IEnumerable<T>' it is each element copy. But creation of 'IList<T>' required more resources rather than to create 'IEnumerable<T>'.

Comment: No, those are interfaces. They are just contracts that do not take any resources. Only concrete classes take resources. When you call the `ToList` extension method on an `IEnumerable<T>` this simply creates a `new List<T>` and feeds the enumerable to the constructor. Of course the underlying elements are not duplicated so you are simply instantiating an object which shouldn't take much memory. The underlying enumerable is stored by reference.

Comment: Yes i agree, "always return the type that's highest in the object hierarchy", it is definitely the way its should be. I think it is the answer to this question.

Comment: Yes i am a bit mix up. To cast from 'List<T>' to 'IEnumerable<T>' it is only reference copy another but way 'IEnumerable<T>' to 'List<T>' it is each element copy. But methods which returning 'IList<T>' required more resources rather than methods which returns  'IEnumerable<T>'